# Save sparse matrix as row, column, and value vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix saved in a `mat` file. I want to process it in C++ but my library expects the sparse matrix to be represented as three vectors: `colIdx` (vector of indices of nonzero columns), `rowIdx` (vector of indices of nonzero rows), and `val` (vector of values).

How should I go about this? Are there any built-in commands doing similar operations?

Answer (score 3):

[`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) is what you are looking for

```
[rowIdx colIdx val] = find( myHugeSparseMatrix );
```

Comment: I get an error (`Out of memory`). Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: @user111691 bummer :( you might need to process your matrix in blocks. One block at a time.

Comment: @user111691 check http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-large-text-files.html Read in part of your data, then export the [rowIdx colIdx val]  of Shai's find